# "wanted me say" or "was wanting me say" in such case?

Tags: american-english, infinitives, subjunctives, progressive-aspect

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

1. I was thinking you wanted me say "Hello."
2. I was thinking you was wanting me say "Hello."
3. I was thinking you want me say "Hello."

Comment: or maybe it would be< i thought you was wanting me say hello>??

Comment: I was thinking you want me **to** say hello

Comment: I **thought** you **had** wanted me to say "hello".

Comment: I was thinking the same thing (when you said that to me).

Answer (score 3):

All the sentences are grammatically incorrect.

First off, you should use to-infinitive "to say" instead of bare infinitive "say".

Second, you need to use the auxiliary verb were for you, not was.

I think correct sentences are as follows:

1. I was thinking you wanted me to say hello.
2. I was thinking you were wanting me to say hello.l
3. I am thinking you want me to say hello.
4. I am thinking you are wanting me to say hello.

You use the verb want in the present and past progressive only in informal conversation; you don't use the verb in the progressive in formal speech or writing.

Comment: Very good, except for the last sentence, which is far too sweeping: there are many occasions where the progressive is entirely proper in the most formal registers. It is true that you rarely encounter these progressive uses of *think* and *want* in formal registers, but that is not because they are prohibited; it is because the characteristic significance of these uses is rarely called for in formal registers.

Comment: StoneyB,  Thanks for your nice comments.  There's a typo in the last sentence. I have corrected it.

Comment: `All the sentences are grammatically incorrect.` - But it took me 3 or 4 attempts to figure out that `to` was missing from the first sentence. My brain just kept putting it in!